# How to set a Background of a CustomView behind the Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, background, android-custom-view

I have got a custom `View` like this:

```
public class ShadowTextView extends TextView {

...

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        final int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        final int minSize = Math.min(parentWidth, parentHeight);

        mShadow = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(
                parentWidth * mCenterX,
                parentHeight * mCenterY,
                minSize * mGradientRadiusWidthPercent,
                new int[]{mStartColor, mCenterColor, mEndColor},
                null,
                android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        mShadow.setDither(true);
        mShadow.setShader(gradient);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), mShadow);

    }

...

}
```

In XML I want to use this `CustomView` with a background which is over my `Canvas`.

```
<com.ShadowTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="+"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="32dp"

    app:startColor="@android:color/black"
    app:centerColor="@android:color/black"
    app:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:gradientRadiusWidthPercent=".5"
/>
```

The circle.xml:

```
<layer-list>

    <item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:bottom="6dp"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp">

        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <!--
                accentColor might be material red #F44336
            -->

            <solid android:color="#F44336" />

        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The `Canvas` shadow is in foreground but should be in background, that means behind the `android:background="@drawable/circly"` and the text.

The current result:

[image: wrong]

The wished result:

[image: correct]

At last an important note:
I know there are a lot of open libraries to get a floating action button. Please don't refer me. I want to find my "own" solution so style a textView.

Comment: "android:background" is (as its name suggests) placed on the background, but you can get background Drawable by calling getBackground()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution was really easy. The background setting by XML definition '`android_background`' is drawn in the `draw(...)` – not in the `onDraw(...)` – method.

So, all what I had to do was to draw my shadow in the `draw(...)` method and then call the `super.draw(...)` method for drawing the background (over my shadow).

Furthermore in the `super.draw(...)` method the `onDraw(...)` method is invoked for drawing the text of the `TextView`.

The same code as above with a little change:

```
public class ShadowTextView extends TextView {

    ...

    // overriding of the draw() method instead of the onDraw(...) method

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), mShadow);

        /*
            Draw the background setting by XML definition android:background
         */
        super.draw(canvas);

    }

    ...

}
```

Thanks for your concern.

Comment: clumsy yet possible pitfall: do not call "setBackground" inside constructor :/